# Get version of Ruby in Windows

Tags: ruby, installation

Downloaded Ruby 1.9.3-p545 on my PC running Windows version 6.1 (Build 7601: SP 1). When checking the version, I'm getting the following error.

```
irb(main):002:0> ruby --version
NameError: undefined local variable or method `version' for main:Object
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Could someone help? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run `ruby --version` from within IRB. Exit IRB using `exit` and then run the command again from the shell prompt.

Alternatively type `RUBY_VERSION` from within IRB to print the version string.